# BizTalk Server: maximum number of receive locations per host

Tags: biztalk

I have more than 900 receive locations associated with the same host.
All receive locations are enabled but sometimes some of them are not working (and are still enabled).
When I disabled and re-enabled it, the receive location works but another one is going into trouble.
Are there any known limitations of the number of receive locations that can be associated with the same host in BizTalk 2016?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a limitation number, but if you associate all the receive locations to the same Host, problably your problems are due to the Throttling mechanism.

Comment: I checked and there is no throttling. The receive location and just doing nothing and are still enabled.

Answer (score 1):

While there are no hard limits to Receive Locations or Send Ports, there are still practical limits based on available resources.

**900 is a lot for a single Host.**  Even if everything was running perfectly, I would still break that up across ~3 Hosts.

If these are File Receive Locations, there are other techniques to reduce the amount even more.  Some options:

1. Use a Windows Scheduler task to move files from various locations to fewer, or maybe one location.  If 'source' information is necessary, you can add a tag to the file name which can be extracted in a custom Pipeline Component.
2. Modify the sample File Adapter in the SDK to scan sub-folders as well.  You can combine this with option 1 if you cannot modify the filename for some reason.
3. Similar to option 1, the script can write a meta-data file before moving the file with any data you need to preserve.  The meta-data can then be read in a Pipeline Component.

Comment: When you speak about "other techniques" for FILE Receive Locations, can you be more specific? Because I have a lot of FILE receive locations.